# Is it possible to derive a formula for any set of random numbers to turn it into a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it **possible** to derive a formula for **any** set of random numbers to turn it into a sequence? I recognise that it would be likely become extremely complex very quickly based on the amount of supposedly random numbers in the sequence and their varied nature.

A brief example from the top of my head with numbers randomly chosen would be: find a formula to derive x and subsequent numbers allowing this set of numbers to be viewed as a sequence: 2, 913, 3.14, -173651, 57.9, x,........

Is this possible (not necessarily feasible) with any set of numbers, of any set size? If not, are there known rules detailing why certain number sets and their order (or other quality or nature) can not be described as a mathematical sequence?

Comment: I find the question confusing. The idea that any set can be well-ordered follows from the Axiom of Choice (if you allow that as an axiom). Any countable set can be put in correspondence with the natural numbers.

Comment: Of course, no formula will really predict the next random sample because the samples are, well, random

Comment: I have just had it pointed out to me that my question is incomplete and impossible to answer without some kind of assumption eg. each subsequent number in the set is based solely on the preceding number (or  relating to combinations of preceding numbers and the expanding  combinations thereof up to the last number in the set to enable a set to be turned into a predictable sequence) Also my choice of the term random was poor and should have been "a number of unknown origin or derivation" rather than random which is by definition unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

See [Lagrange Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) - you can fit a $n$ points through a $n-1$ polynomial.